# How to deal with Single Radio button on a Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a scenario where i have a single Radio button on screen. I want it to act like a checkbox, so a user can select or deselect that radio button. Right now if user clicks on radio button, there is no way he can un-check that radio button.

Kindly guide me how to uncheck radio button.

**Radio Button XML**

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Remember me"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    style="@style/radionbutton"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/grayCheckoutFont"
    />
```

Comment: Use a checkbox instead of a RadioButton, RadioButtons are used to select a single option from multiple options like in a quiz app. A checkbox is used whenever you want to enable or disable a setting

Comment: Use checkbox with custom drawable you'll get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RadioButton rb;

rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb);


if(rb.isChecked())
{
  \\ is checked  set it unchecked here
  rb.setChecked(false);
}
else
{
  \\ not checked
}
```

Try it

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with this would be to use a Checkbox widget provided as a RadioButton isn't ideal in this situation. Still this is quite achievable.
Preetika Kaur's code is fine but would uncheck the RadioButton as soon as i enable it. However there is an easy work around this too.
Here is an example using Butterknife.

```
    int i = 0;
    @BindView(R.id.btn) RadioButton btn;

    @OnClick(R.id.btn)
    public void go(RadioButton btn) {
      if(i == 0){
        i++;
        btn.setChecked(true);
      }else{
        i = 0;
        if(btn.isChecked()){
           btn.setChecked(false);
        }else{
          // Not Checked 
        }
      }
    }


/* 
  Other Code
*/

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    // TODO Make App
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
full_pay_check.setChecked(!full_pay_check.isChecked());
```